# can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes - last_seen option

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime, flask

I want to update the user last seen column. To do that i am trying this user model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    def ping(self):
        self.last_seen = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

---

And this code that run always when the user execute some action.

```
@mod.before_app_request
def before_request():
    current_user.ping()
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

How can i solve this? I am using postgres and the problem is easily simulated with the code that i am showing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create an aware datetime (a datetime which has a timezone):

```
import pytz

self.last_seen = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

In this case you'll want to create an aware datetime with the current time in UTC.

You'll need the [`pytz`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) package for this (this package contains the latest timezone information and that information isn't part of the Python standard library).